# Need good reference or a proof on regularity of solution to Neumann problem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, reference-works

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d $ be a bounded open subset  ($d\in \mathbb{N}$) and denote  $\partial\Omega$  its boundary which we assume to be Lipschitz.  The classical inhomogeneous Neumann problem for Laplace operator  associate to data   $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g: \partial\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (measurable functions) consists on finding a function  $u:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying

\begin{equation}\label{eqlocal-Neumann}\tag{$N_1$}
-\Delta u = f  \quad\text{in}~~~ \Omega \quad\quad\text{ and } \quad\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=  g ~~~ \text{on}~~~ \partial \Omega.
\end{equation}

In the standard setting one usually choose $ f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ or  in the dual space of $H^1(\Omega)$ and $g$ can be choose in the trace spaces of $H^1(\Omega)$ denote by $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$ or in its dual $H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\partial\Omega)$.

Assume  $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and $g \in H^{3/2}(\Omega)$ then we have the following the Green-Gauss formula

$$\label{eqgreen-Gauss}
\int_{\Omega} (-\Delta) u v \, \mathrm{d}x  =  \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x- \int_{\partial \Omega} \gamma_{1} u \gamma_{0}v \, \mathrm{d}\sigma(x), \quad u\in H^{2}(\Omega) ~\hbox{and}~v\in H^{1}(\Omega).
$$

Henceforth, on $\partial \Omega$ we merely write $\gamma_0 v= v$ and  $ \displaystyle\gamma_1 v=\displaystyle  \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu} $.

Clearly from this green gauss  formula, if $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$ and solves \eqref{eqlocal-Neumann}  then $u $ satisfies the variational problem

$$\label{eqlocalvar-Neumann}\tag{$V_1$}
   \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x=  \int_{\partial \Omega} f v \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial \Omega}gv \, \mathrm{d}\sigma(x), \qquad \hbox{for all } ~~v\in H^{1}(\Omega).
$$
In particular if we put $v=1$ the above formulation becomes
$$\label{eqlocalcompatible-Neumann}\tag{$C_1$}
 \int_{\Omega}f\mathrm{d}x+  \int_{\partial \Omega}g\mathrm{d}\sigma(x)=0
$$
which is the is the compatibility condition.

Viceversa we have the following **global regularity result**.

**Theorem**

Assume $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is bounded open with $C^2$-boundary. If a  function $ u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ is  solution to \eqref{eqlocal-Neumann} with $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and $g \in H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)$ then it belongs to $ H^{2}(\Omega).$

> **Question:** In which book or recommendable reference can I find the proof of the above theorem`?
>    I know that the of this Theorem for the corresponding Dirichlet problem has been done in the book by Brezis or by Evans. Patently, both references avoid the inhomogenous Neumann problem.

**Remark**
Moreover, observe that  if $u$ solves  \eqref{eqlocal-Neumann} or \eqref{eqlocalvar-Neumann}  so does $\tilde{u} = u+c$ for every $c\in\mathbb{R} $ (that is invariant under additive constant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has already a bounty winning answer: however, since I found it interesting, upvoted it the very first day it was posted, and found unusual difficulties in finding a nice answer, I nevertheless want to share my own researches and thoughts.

The only reference I am aware of which gives a proof of this result, is the textbook by Mikhailov [1]. Precisely, he deals with the regularity problem for the first boundary problem (Dirichlet problem) and the second boundary problem (Neumann problem) for the Poisson equation in §2.3, pp. 216-226. Mikhailov proves the result directly: he first solves the problem in the case of *homogeneous boundary conditions*, proving the following theorem:

**Theorem 4 ([[1], p. 217](https://archive.org/details/MikhailovPartialDifferentialEquations/page/n221)).** If $f\in H^k(\Omega)$ and $\partial\Omega\in C^{k+2}$ for certain $k\ge 0$, then the generalized solutions $u(x)$ of the first and second boundary-value problems with homogeneous boundary condition for the Poisson equation belong to $H^{k+2}(\Omega)$ and satisfy (in the case of the second boundary problem it is assumed that $\int_\Omega u \mathrm{d}x=0$) the inequality
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{ H^{k+2}(\Omega)}\le C\Vert f\Vert_{ H^{k}(\Omega)}
$$
where the constant $C>0$ does not depend on f.

By using this result, he extends the regularity theorem 4 above to the case of non homogeneous boundary conditions ([[2], p. 226](https://archive.org/details/MikhailovPartialDifferentialEquations/page/n229)) by reducing non homogeneous boundary conditions to homogeneous ones. He explicitly does it only for the Dirichlet problem but the same method nevertheless works for the Neumann problem: let's see this. Consider a solution $u(x)$ of the problem \eqref{eqlocalvar-Neumann} above and a function $\Phi\in H^{k+2}(\Omega)$ whose normal derivative on $\partial\Omega$ is $g\in H^{k+3/2}(\partial\Omega)$, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\nu}=g\;\text{ on }\;\partial\Omega\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Define $w=u-\Phi$: then, for every $v\in H^{1}(\Omega)$, 
$$\label{GeneralizedNeumann}\tag{GN}
\begin{split}
   \int_{\Omega} \nabla w \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x&=\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{\Omega} \nabla \Phi \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x \\
  &=  \int_\Omega f v \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial \Omega}gv \, \mathrm{d}\sigma(x) - \int_{\Omega} \nabla \Phi \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_\Omega f v \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial \Omega}gv \, \mathrm{d}\sigma(x) - \int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot(v\nabla\Phi) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\Omega} v\Delta\Phi \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_\Omega \big[\,f + \Delta\Phi\big]v\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial \Omega}gv \, \mathrm{d}\sigma(x) - \int_{\partial\Omega} \nu \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\nu} \, \mathrm{d}\sigma(x),
\end{split}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
and substituting \eqref{1} in \eqref{2} we get
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla w \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x=\int_\Omega f_1 v \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
where $f_1=f+\Delta\Phi\in H^k(\Omega)$. This means that $w$ solves the Neumann  problem \eqref{eqlocalvar-Neumann} with homogeneous boundary conditions (i.e. $g\equiv 0$), and by applying theorem 4 we have 
$$
w=u-\Phi\in H^{k+2}(\Omega) \iff u=w+\Phi\in H^{k+2}(\Omega) 
$$

**Notes**

- In Mikhailov's notation, $H^0=L^2$: also he does not use the standard notation for traces, for example expressing that $\varphi\in H^{1/2}(\partial G)$ by saying that $\varphi$ is a function in $L^2(\partial G)$ which is the *trace* of a function $\Phi\in H^1(G)$.
- Regarding the third boundary problem (the so called Robin problem), Mikhailov  ([[1], footnote *, p. 217](https://archive.org/details/MikhailovPartialDifferentialEquations/page/n221)) remarks that analysis of the regularity of solutions can be dealt as done in theorem 4 above for the solutions to the first and second boundary value problems, provided certain conditions are assumed.

[1] V. P. Mikhailov (1978), *[Partial differential equations](https://archive.org/details/MikhailovPartialDifferentialEquations)*, Translated from the Russian by P.C. Sinha. Revised from the 1976 Russian ed., Moscow: Mir Publishers, p. 396 [MR0601389](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0601389), [Zbl 0388.3500](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0388.35002).

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I will check the book. at the moment we don't have it in our library. I will come back to you for a possible reward.

Comment: @GuyFsone: you can download a .pdf copy of it from the link I provided in the reference. It is perfectly legal as the book is made available from the Archive.org.

Comment: Thanks I will do hoping it is not illegal

Comment: @GuyFsone: do not worry. The are part of a big digitalization initiative which includes Google and several North American Universities.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri

Do you have a reference for the surjectivity of the Neumann trace?

Comment: @Leonardo: I'm not sure. I have to check.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri This would be great, thank you.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri (asking because it doesn't seem to be the case, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01210400, p. 511, bottom)

Comment: @Leonardo, thinking about your question I just remembered that, due to condition \eqref{eqlocalvar-Neumann}, you cannot have surjectivity of the Neumann trace. This is simply due to the fact that the Neumann boundary condition must satisfy this compatibility condition, otherwise [solvability of the problem fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214541/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-the-solution-of-neumann-problem/3215655#3215655). And as simple examples show, \eqref{eqlocalvar-Neumann} cannot be satisfied by every function $g\in L^1(\partial G)$

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thinking about it more, it seems to actually be the case. Theorem 1.5.1.2 of Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains from Grisvard confirms. So, in your case $k=0$, you can select $\Phi$ as you explained, would you agree?

Here is what I am referring to: https://prnt.sc/cmczA3u0O2sD

Comment: @Leonardo, I apologize for my late answer to your nice comments. The result from Grisvard's monograph you cite is correct and very explicit. The route Mikhailov takes seems different: he proves a surjectivity result of $C^k(\partial G)$ in $C^k(\overline{G})$ ($G$ is assumed $C^k$) and then proves the density of this function space in $H^k(G)$. Considering the density of $C^1(\partial G)$ in $$L^2(\partial G)$, this is somewhat equivalent. If you think the answer will benefit from this, I'll add a note.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Yes, I would say a short note might be useful for the people to come !

Answer (score 6):

A standard reference is the book of Grisvard Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains [Grisvard](http://bookstore.siam.org/cl69/). Chapter 2 is about regularity of elliptic equations in smooth domains. The theorem you want is Theorem 2.2.2.5. As for proofs, Grisvard mainly deals with the Dirichlet case and then in a short remark explains how to modify it for Neumann. It might not be what you want.
If you want all the proofs, take a look at Theorems 130- 136 in these lectures notes. [lecture notes](http://giovannileoni.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/0/5/31054371/pde-i-lectures-2013-12-07-signed.pdf)